# Espresso: Clicking button on Dialog above ScrollView doesn't work

Tags: android, android-espresso

So I had a layout with this view hierarchy:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ... >
  <TableLayout ... >
    ...
  </TableLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Over this layout, I showed custom DialogFragment. In Espresso test I've closed it like that:

```
onView(withText("Save")).perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

I've changed the layout, adding `ScrollView` around `TableLayout`. Now it looks more like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ... >
  <ScrollView ...>
    <TableLayout ... >
      ...
    </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's this [commit](https://github.com/kirillsmirnov1/Friends-reminder-android/commit/9279929740a47f25a1c75b0d36c3d0d5c011857d)

And that **Espresso line doesn't close dialog anymore**.

I've tried several other ways of closing it like

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());
```

and

```
onView(withText("Save"))
            .inRoot(isDialog())
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            .perform(click());
```

and

```
UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
uiDevice.findObject((new UiSelector().text("Save"))).click();
```

but none of them close the dialog.

The funny thing is, the test fails not because of unsuccessful click itself, but because it can't find view (hidden by dialog) from the next line.

Answer (score 0):

It is common behavior for test to fail, if the dialog is shown over views that need to be found by Espresso. 
What I recommend is to use **UiAutomatorViewer**, which can be found in
`{AndroidSdkPath}\tools\bin\`. Using this tool, take a screenshot of the dialog (trigger it manually) and retrieve button's id (sometimes dialog's button id may differ from `android.R.id.button1`).

Use this value with method `onView(withId(retrievedId)).perform(click());`.

You should always use id values as selectors for views in instrumentation tests, since views' text may depend on localization of device/emulator.

Comment: I've run UiAutomatorViewer and it's still `button1`. And using `onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());` still dosen't work.